# What is this- BoC.Web.Mvc.PrecompiledViews.ApplicationPartRegistry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to compile in ASP .NET MVC 3 project my Views to dll,- that's ok, but when i register dlls, i have problem here:

```
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dll.FullName);
            // register compiled razor views
            // e.g. 'settings.cshtml' is registered as '~/extensions/plugins/rating/settings.cshtml'
            BoC.Web.Mvc.PrecompiledViews.ApplicationPartRegistry.Register(assembly, pluginDir);
```

I can't understand, what's that- BoC?

Source: http://mikakolari.fi/2011/02/aspnetmvc-3-plugin-architecture-with-embedded-razor-views/

---

**Solution**:
When u compile your Views, u have 2 files in bin/Debug:

- Commons.Web.Mvc.PrecompiledViews.dll
- Crash.PageRating.dll

So, BoC.Web.Mvc.PrecompiledViews.ApplicationPartRegistry is in **Commons.Web.Mvc.PrecompiledViews.dll** which u have to Add to your project.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get that MSDN link to work. The `BoC` stuff is by [Chris van de Steeg](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/) and the source code is [here](https://github.com/csteeg/BoC) and `Commons.Web.Mvc.PrecompiledViews.dll` specifically is [here](https://github.com/csteeg/BoC/tree/master/Src/Commons.Web.PrecompiledViews).

Having said all of that, in [this blog post](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/) Chris seems to recommend using David Ebbo's [razorgenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

By now, this is all integrated in the `RazorGenerator.Mvc` NuGet package. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33263732/331281.